# Instruction Pointer vs Program Counter?

Tags: assembly, cpu, cpu-architecture, cpu-registers, program-counter

Is there any basic difference between instruction pointer and program counter? I believe they both refer to the same thing, the eip/rip register, although with the research i have done so far it is not very clear in my mind.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Nope, they're the same thing. A given architecture will refer to exactly one of these (in particular, x86 and x64 use IP instead of PC).